# What is this yellow ray flowering plant, found in Lynchburg, VA, that honey bees like?

Tags: identification, flowers

The flowers have slender petals.

My honey bees seem to like it!

[image]

Comment: looks like a sunflower/lettuce family plant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its [*Verbesina alternifolia*](http://plants.usda.gov/core/profile?symbol=VEAL), commonly known as Wingstem or Yellow Iron Weed. It appears to be native to your area, particularly around and in woods, and has become naturalized in other areas in Central North America.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This flower is a [*Senecio sp.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senecio)..

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senecio), there are 1500 species in the _Senecio_ genus: please try to narrow it down a little further. Additionally, update your post to say **why** you believe your identification is correct: what plant characteristics do you see in the photograph that led you to that identification. Thanks!